# Internet access and sharing using only router and without ICS

Tags: router, internet, internet-sharing

I want to share my internet connection between two computers. I have got D-link dwr-113 router. I want to use this router to share internet. My ISP provides static ip based internet connection along with captive portal based authentication (usr/pass). How do I configure my router for this? I do not want to avoid Windows based ICS.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, but I think your IPS should be able to help you with that.

Comment: @Ariane: See I am able to connect to the internet using both of my computers through the router. The problems comes when both the computers are accessing internet simultaneously - none is able to load the page. Hope it is clear now.